# update-ca-trust extract not adding certificates to ca-bundle

Tags: centos, certificates

```
CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)
Kernel 5.1.11-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64
```

I put a cert-file to `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors`

File looks like that:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDojCCAoqgAwIBAgIQeqkpty5ghoxP8YfCRe+7qjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBP
some strings
FnpKVwAq6UcYOu4AoXweaqOOMsLNSw==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

And after `update-ca-trust extract` I expect to see my cert in the bundle-file `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt` but there was nothing new in it. And `ls -al` show me latest edit time, so It was changed 2 monts ago, not now.

Initially I try this with `.crt` file. But renaming `.crt` to `.pem` didn't solve my problem.
I also tried `update-ca-trust enable` and `update-ca-trust force-enable` before extract, but it didn't help.
`/var/log/messages` says nothing about that.

What I shell do to fix it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**TL;DR**

The `update-ca-trust` won't extract your certificate file to the `ca-bundle.crt` unless this succeeds:

```
openssl x509 -noout -text -in <cert_file> | grep --after-context=2 "X509v3 Basic Constraints" | grep "CA:TRUE"
```

---

I spent a few hours on this issue. Its root was in a X.509 extension called [Basic Constraints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509#Extensions_informing_a_specific_usage_of_a_certificate) which is used to mark whether a certificate belongs to a CA or not.

My humble findings:

1. The `update-ca-bundle` tool is in fact a shell script, so it's easy to peek inside
2. The script calls `p11-kit` utility multiple times each time using different filter and creating different bundle files.
3. The file `ca-bundle.crt` is in fact a link from `tls-ca-bundle.pem` file which is generated by `p11-kit` using `ca-anchors` filter. So it ignores all certs besides "CA ones".
4. If a certificate is or is not a CA is decided by *Basic Constraints* X.509 extension. This way it's possible to mark a certificate as a part of a CA.
5. It's possible to list all X.509 extensions using `openssl x509 -noout -text -in <cert_file>`
6. So any certificate file not labelled as a part of a CA will be filtered out by `p11-kit` and not exported to the desired `ca-bundle.crt` file.

Feel free to correct this in comments.

Comment: how to make it work that is not part of CA?
the cert has: CA:FALSE

Comment: Thank you! this validation works great! After verified, adding root CAs may vary slightly across distros. Copy the cert to /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors Then run sudo update-ca-trust extract This should update the files in /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/... which are typically linked back to /etc/pki/tls/certs

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what you are asking but the steps below work for me. I enable 'ca trust', copy over the file, extract, and then verify.

```
$ update-ca-trust enable
$ cp ZScalar.pem /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/
cp: overwrite ‘/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/ZScalar.pem’? yes
$ update-ca-trust extract
$ openssl verify  ZScalar.crt
ZScalar.crt: OK
```

If these steps don't work please post the output of the "openssl verify" command and I might be able to direct you further.

To add to this, extracted certs go to "/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/openssl" or "/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem".

Answer (score 0):

1.get ca cert's issue

```
openssl x509 -in ca.crt -noout -text |grep -i "issue"
```

output like below:

```
Issuer: CN=something_strings
```

2.find issue in /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt

```
grep -i "something_strings" /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

output like below:

```
something_strings
```

if you can get result, then your certs is added with success.

you need to reboot server for take affect.

Comment: I see my `something_strings` in `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt` but when I `curl https://mysite:443` or `wget https://mysite:443`, I still get `ERROR: cannot verify <url>'s certificate, issued by '/C=.../ST=.../L=.../O=.../OU=.../CN=...': Self-signed certificate encountered`.  I did think a reboot was necessary but I'll try that now since I'm here.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was just because i was not using `sudo`

Copy the CA certificate to `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors`, then call below command

```
sudo update-ca-trust extract
```

After this check the exit code, should be 0

```
echo $?
```

OR grep CA certificate name in below file for confirmation

```
cat /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/tls-ca-bundle.pem | grep "CA-cert-name"
```

Answer (score 0):

The CA certifications should be in place on the system within the ca-trust bundle. The "openssl x509" command is expecting to operate against a single PEM encoded certificate at a time. Since the underlying bundle has many certificates included, only the first is displayed.

To show all issuers:

```
openssl crl2pkcs7 -nocrl -certfile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt | openssl pkcs7 -print_certs | grep subject | head
```