# CentOS - update-ca-trust extract not populating certificates to ca-bundle.crt

Tags: centos, certificates

I am a new linux administrator and I have an issue with a certificate authority. I am working on that for a few days now and none of the manuals/blogs/forums I have read can help me (or maybe I am too low ^^ )

I am using CentOS 7.9.2009.

I have the same issue as this topic [update-ca-trust extract not adding certificates to ca-bundle](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/525601/update-ca-trust-extract-not-adding-certificates-to-ca-bundle)
but it did not solve my issue.

I have a self root CA which I am not able to add to `ca-bundle.crt` with the `update-ca-trust` (`extract` or without `extract`). The result is the same. My ca-bundle.crt file is not populated with my certificate while the last modification date is updated.

My certificate is in `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors` in `.crt` format.
It has the `Basic Constraints X.509 extension` saying it is a `CA:TRUE`.

My CA certificate can be added successfully on some machines but cannot be added on some others.
A new CA certificate (for testing) can be added successfully.

So, I think there is a mess with in the configuration of some servers, maybe some files edited manually in the past, or something in the cache, or maybe a wrong/broken symbolic link... well, I don't know at the moment.

I have `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt -> /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/tls-ca-bundle.pem` and this file does not contain my root CA.

But this file `/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/openssl/ca-bundle.trust.crt` does.

My main question is, how to fix this so I can populate the ca-bundle.crt with my root CA ?

Any body could help me resolving this ?

Thanks a lot.